# firefox not centering main div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to center a main div using margin:0px auto; but it wont work in firefox. It works in  Chrome and IE any idea why this happend.

css:

```
#mami{


width:1200px;

margin:0px auto;


}
```

html:

```
<body>

<div id='mami'>
   <h1>Center Me</h1>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Let's see more of your code.

Comment: this is all i have to do but it wont work in FireFox

Comment: You have no content in the div.  How can you tell it isn't centered?

Comment: It's centered fine in Firefox.

Comment: 0px is unnecessary. null is the same null in any measurement unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div is centered fine in Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/nTXeq/2/

[image]

If you want to center the text within the div, you'll need to target that specifically:

```
#mami {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting without px like margin: 0 auto; but you have to add something inside the div tag or else nothing will show and you have nothing to see.

```
<style>.asdf{background:silver;width:1200px;margin:0 auto;height:20px}</style><div class="asdf">Should Center</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a DIV around this with a name of like wraper with a width of 100%. Then center this element inside f that using:

HTML:

```
<div id="globalContainer">
    <div id="mami">
        This is some text!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#globalContainer{
    width:100%;
}

#mami{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1200;
}
```